# HighChart table with tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here we have code `jsfiddle.net/zvgnq84v`
Is it possible to add Highchart tooltip(for example). I mean not to implement myself, but just call internal ready HighChart functions.

Comment: You simply need to implement them. I'm not sure where is the problem. You know, there are events in html/js like mouseover, mouseout etc..

Comment: When I was implementing myself it I have some problems that Highchart uses svg, not html tags(if 
I understand correctly). So one of problem was to get absolute position of tag. Here I meant that is it possible to call ready HighChart functions. I edited my question, sorry that put it unclear

Comment: Why you cannot skip highcharts part, and use html table then catch mousevent by jquery and print any div "above" col/row ?

Comment: I need to save table, I have not any ideas how it is possible to do without HighChart

Comment: I meant something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zvgnq84v/2/ - I'm not sure why do you need absolute position of the tag..? Anyway, each object in Highcharts has `getBBox()` method which returns bounding box of the element.

Comment: Or use any html2pdf tools, like wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need absolute possition to show use Jquery and show my tooltip near the pie piece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you put up this question. But if you go through http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip there is in-built functionality available for tooltip in highchart

May be I am missing something.